# How can I debug random freeze,which causing visual studio crash together?

Tags: .net, winforms, debugging, crash

It just freeze randomly, no responding, no exception thrown, both in release/debug mode. (usually hours latter after started)

In debug mode, when the freezing occured, if I set any breakpoint in visual studio,or pause, it freezes at once as well, until I kill the vs and the program respectively in taskmgr.

My program has no unmanaged code, no p/v, and I just change very few, put something even irrelevant inside a try-catch loop. 
I checked my code again and have no clue why it freezes with such changes.

Any help?

This is the most plausible cause the freeze(This is a delegate of a background thread!)

It was only

> File.Delete(di.Path);

I changed to this:

```
while (true)
                            {
                                try {
                                    File.Delete(di.Path);
                                    break;
                                }
                                catch (Exception exex)
                                {
                                    Logger.Log("2827 form1 cs unable to delete: " + exex.Message);
                                    Thread.Sleep(500);
                                }
                            }
```

I can't imagine it will cause such situation if it is really the reason. According to the log the crash is before theh delegate.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you suspect to cause the freeze. We can't magically guess what causes your issue.

Comment: @Tobias Tengler If I can, I already post. It is impossible to upload my program because the data is private and only specified data cause crash, so I am looking for a proper method to debug rather than ask someone debug for me

Comment: Could you check your resource usage during debugging? I find it odd that Visual Studio is crashing as well, maybe your CPU is maxed out or you're out of memory.

Comment: @Tobias Tengler I am pretty sure the cpu、memory、gdi、 handle is normal( At least when I notice is is so.)